# Redux persist problem - state is not saved locally

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-saga, redux-persist, react-typescript

## Problem with redux-persist

I am working on a react typescript application. I have implemented redux-persist but it seems data is not saved in localstorage. My code is below. Reply as fast an possible.

It is rehydrating at the begining but not saving nor retrieving data from localstorage.

## configureStore.ts

```js
/**
 * Create the store with dynamic reducers
 */

import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { createInjectorsEnhancer } from 'redux-injectors';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import { createReducer } from './reducers';
// imports for presist store
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import autoMergeLevel2 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2';

// persist config
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  // blacklist: ['extra'],
  // whitelist: ['auth'],
  // stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2,
  storage,
}

export function configureAppStore() {
  const reduxSagaMonitorOptions = {};
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware(reduxSagaMonitorOptions);
  const { run: runSaga } = sagaMiddleware;

  // Create the store with saga middleware
  const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware];

  const enhancers = [
    createInjectorsEnhancer({
      createReducer,
      runSaga,
    }),
  ];

  const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, createReducer());

  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    middleware: [...getDefaultMiddleware(), ...middlewares],
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    enhancers,
  });

  const persistor = persistStore(store);

  return {store, persistor};
}
```

## reducers.ts

```js
/**
 * Combine all reducers in this file and export the combined reducers.
 */

import { combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import { InjectedReducersType } from 'utils/types/injector-typings';

/**
 * Merges the main reducer with the router state and dynamically injected reducers
 */
export function createReducer(injectedReducers: InjectedReducersType = {}) {
  // Initially we don't have any injectedReducers, so returning identity function to avoid the error
  if (Object.keys(injectedReducers).length === 0) {
    return state => state;
  } else {
    return combineReducers({
      ...injectedReducers,
    });
  }
}
```

## Slice/index.ts

```js
import { selectAuthLoading } from './selectors';
import { PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { createSlice } from 'utils/@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { useInjectReducer, useInjectSaga } from 'utils/redux-injectors';
import { authSaga } from './saga';
import { AuthState } from './types';

export const initialState: AuthState = {
  isLoggedIn: false,
  token: '',
  user: {
    name: '',
    email: '',
  },
  extras: {
    screenLoading: false,
    authLoading: false,
  },
};

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    loginUser(
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<{
        email: string;
        password: string;
      }>,
    ) {},
    setLoggedIn(state, action: PayloadAction<boolean>) {
      state.isLoggedIn = action.payload;
    },
    setToken(state, action: PayloadAction<string>) {
      state.token = action.payload;
    },
    setAuthLoading(state, action: PayloadAction<boolean>) {
      state.extras.authLoading = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { actions: authActions } = slice;

export const useAuthSlice = () => {
  useInjectReducer({ key: slice.name, reducer: slice.reducer });
  useInjectSaga({ key: slice.name, saga: authSaga });
  return { actions: slice.actions };
};
```

## index.tsx

```js
/**
 * index.tsx
 *
 * This is the entry file for the application
 */

import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';

import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

// Use consistent styling
import 'sanitize.css/sanitize.css';

// Import root app
import { App } from 'app';

import { HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';

import { configureAppStore } from 'store/configureStore';

import reportWebVitals from 'reportWebVitals';

// Redux Persist imports
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';

// Initialize languages
import './locales/i18n';
// Components
import { ScreenLoader } from './app/components/ScreenLoader';

const { store, persistor } = configureAppStore();
const MOUNT_NODE = document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement;

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={<ScreenLoader />} persistor={persistor}>
        <HelmetProvider>
          <React.StrictMode>
            <App />
          </React.StrictMode>
        </HelmetProvider>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  MOUNT_NODE,
);

// Hot reloadable translation json files
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept(['./locales/i18n'], () => {
    // No need to render the App again because i18next works with the hooks
  });
}
reportWebVitals();
```

## saga.ts

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { take, call, put, select, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { authActions as actions } from '.';
import { API_URL } from './../../../utils/constants';
import { User } from './../../../API';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';

// Logging in the user
// function* loginUserSaga(payload: {email: string, password: string}){
function* loginUserSaga(action: any) {
  try {
    yield put({ type: actions.setAuthLoading.type, payload: true });
    const response = yield call(User.getUser, action.payload);
    if (response && response.data || response.data === '') {
      yield put({ type: actions.setAuthLoading.type, payload: false });
      yield put({type: actions.setToken.type, payload: response.data.data.accessToken});
      toast(response.data.message, {
        type:
          response.data.message.toLowerCase() === 'success'
            ? 'success'
            : 'warning',
      });
    } else {
      yield put({ type: actions.setAuthLoading.type, payload: false });
      toast('Unknown error!', {
        type: 'error',
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({ type: actions.setAuthLoading.type, payload: false });
    toast(error.message, {
      type: 'error',
    });
  }
}
// Setting logged in user
function* setLoggedSaga(payload: any) {
  yield put({ type: actions.setAuthLoading.type, payload: true });
  console.log(payload);
  yield put({ type: actions.setAuthLoading.type, payload: false });
}

export function* authSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(actions.setLoggedIn.type, setLoggedSaga);
  yield takeLatest(actions.loginUser.type, loginUserSaga);
}
```

Comment: Try placing the PersistGate in App.tsx instead of index.tsx